# How to get an s3 object url in lambda (python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In my configuration S3 triggers a lambda function and function needs to have the object url
Let's say I have the S3 put event json

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "example-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test%2Fkey",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I saw these lines in the documentation but it doesn't get me the object url

```
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

So what would be the solution here?

Comment: Have you seen an object url before? Should not be difficult do figure out which parts the bucket name and key are.

Comment: I came up with this ("https://" + bucket + ".s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/" + key)
Thanks man